# does drupal path module affect other modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-hooks

Have been asked to shift a custom made module of drupal site to another site (which is based on Openpublish d7). That module primarily is for providing web service data when a specific url is called (thus the module is implementing menu_hook).

However when adding and activating the module on the new site, it gives an error when that specific url is called that page does not exist.

First the assumption was that Openpublish may not have hooks but recently saw the `path` module installed (which in my knowledge required the menu hook).

Now the question was that whether it is possible that the `path` module may be causing issues for the custom module's menu hook to work properly.. ? if so, can there be any workarounds. cannot possibly turn off the path module as i have only been asked to add this new module and the site is already live (so experimentation may not be a choice :) )

Any help appreciated..

Comment: is the new site on a different server? It may be a URL rewriting issue.

Comment: thank you for the comment. yes its a new server and different drupal.

Answer (score 0):

issue seems to have been solved after clearing the drupal cache . wasn't actually considering cache at that time.

thought to answer in case it helps others as well :)